# How do I implement a box with an image in the corner and text inside?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement something similar to below.  I want some text in a box and an icon in the top left. The icon should remain on the top left even if the page resizes.

I am trying to implement it in the context of a bootstrap page.  I've unsuccessfully tried using the `jumbotron` but I don't think it was meant for this purpose.

What approach should I take?

[image]

Comment: You should try and use z-index and have the image overlapping a div and use bootstrap or @media queries for the resizing issues

Comment: Put an `<img src='red_house.png' />` inside the black text HTML Element. Make the black text box, `position:relative;`. Make the red house `position:absolute; top:-50px; left:-50px;` or something like that.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @DavidG Yes, and I see my error (now that I've seen suggestions).  I was trying to put a border around a bootstrap row and then set the img to negative margins.  It was having too many unintended consequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a case for pseudo elements as the house is an icon.

```css
.realestate {
  border:2px black solid;
  padding: 75px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px
}

.realestate::after{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100px; /*Width of image*/
  height: 100px; /*Height of image*/
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: -50px;
  background-image:url(https://www.fillmurray.com/100/100);
}
```

```html
<section class="realestate">
Cras dolor purus, posuere non iaculis vel, vulputate eu tellus. Cras tempus dapibus mi nec euismod. Pellentesque dapibus magna ac venenatis varius. Quisque sed cursus ex, sit amet luctus sapien. Mauris eget quam turpis. In laoreet arcu sed ipsum faucibus, eget hendrerit quam ornare. Sed condimentum quam vitae nisl tincidunt ornare. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nullam vel pretium leo. Vestibulum pulvinar elit sed nisl rhoncus maximus. Proin bibendum viverra leo non tristique. Morbi varius leo ac lobortis luctus. Pellentesque fermentum dui quis nisl molestie iaculis. Sed imperdiet eget quam finibus lacinia. Fusce sed mauris porta, fermentum mauris nec, lobortis lorem. Praesent sollicitudin tristique purus ut imperdiet.

</section>
```

Obviously, replace Bill with the image of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.text{
  margin: 50px 0px 0px 50px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.image-1{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
text text text text text 
text text text text text 
text text text text text 
text text text text text 
text text text text text 
text text text text text 
text text text text text 
text text text text text 
</div>
<img src="https://mylocal-media.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/file_asset/file/13234/housestamp.png" class="image-1" />
```

heres some simple code that might be what you are looking for.  Let me know if you need further help.